# Is it possible to open file upload window on click hypertext using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function performClick(node)
{
   var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
   evt.initEvent("click", true, false);
   node.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="performClick(document.getElementById('theFile'));">
    Open file dialog
</a>
<input type="file" id="theFile"/>
```

This code although satisfies the basic criteria of opening the file upload window, what i would like to have is that input type = "file" field to be hidden on my webpage.

Any Idea folks?

Comment: just use a <label for=file1>

Comment: It's pretty hard to do anything tricky with `<input type="file" />` for security reasons..

Comment: @dandavis Agreed. That can then be styled to look like a hyperlink if OP prefers.

Comment: the <label> tag is easy to style and you can click on it from anywhere, not just around the input itself. i use hidden inputs and label to make a nice drop-down menu with an upload option...

Comment: @sanki http://jsfiddle.net/XhvzA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add style to your theFile, either `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean download, or this question makes no sense. You can link to a `.zip` or `.7z` file extension, or any file extension that your server or the browser won't try to interpret, or send the correct headers. See:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/php/ht/force_download.htm

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: No, they're talking about *uploading* a file through a `<form>`

Comment: @sanki - This question isn't protected, you should be able to post an answer with 7 rep.

Comment: @sanki - Weird, are you trying to post an answer [with more than 2 links](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user)?